# Faster compiling

Tags: listings, compiling, draft, performance

I'm writing at my thesis and it has now about 60 pages.. When I want to compile it (to pdf), it lasts about 20 seconds.. Is it normal? I think, the included graphics costs a lot of time?!

Unfortunately I don't have much experience in LaTeX...

But I discovered the draft mode.. There it compiles much faster... But it omits beside the graphics also the lstlistings in my code..

In the draft of my thesis, I don't need the graphics, but the code snippets (embedded in lstlistings) would be nice..

Are there any possibilities to get this? Fast compiling and lstlistings..

Comment: Are you using the `draft` as option in the class or in the `graphicx` package?

Comment: a 190pp doc i regularly compile takes 2.5 seconds with latex, 7 seconds with pdflatex; so pdflatex itself is one source of your problem.  (i suspect graphics in pdflatex are worse still, in comparison, since they have to be copied to the output, whereas latex merely puts a \special command into the output stream.  (my doc doesn't have any graphics at all.)

Comment: mh, Sigur, I use the draft option in the documentclass!

Comment: split your document into multiple files and then use `include` and `includeonly`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could compile everything in your document in draft mode except for the graphics by passing the `draft` option to your documentclass and then the `final` option, which is the inverse of `draft` to `listings`.

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{listings}
```